# How to return selected check boxes using wxPython?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I want to perform following tasks but not getting there:

1] Get checked options under 'OnApply'

2] Once I checked few options then 'Select' or 'UnSelectAll' will only not select/unselect those options which were not selected/selected manually?

Do I need to index all check box options to do above tasks?

Any help to accomplish this would be very appreciative. Please let me know if its not clear.

```
import wx

class MyCheckBox(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Checking Options', size=(470, 400))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.cb = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, '', (120, 75))
        self.cb.SetValue(False)
        self.cb = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, '', (200, 75))
        self.cb.SetValue(False)
        self.cb = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, '', (278, 75))
        self.cb.SetValue(False)
        self.cb = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, '', (356, 75))
        self.cb.SetValue(False)

        self.cb = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, '', (120, 105))
        self.cb.SetValue(False)
        self.cb = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, '', (200, 105))
        self.cb.SetValue(False)
        self.cb = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, '', (278, 105))
        self.cb.SetValue(False)
        self.cb = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, '', (356, 105))
        self.cb.SetValue(False)


        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Send output to File", (70, 255))
        self.cb = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, '', (50, 255))
        self.cb.SetValue(True)

        wx.EVT_CHECKBOX(self, self.cb.GetId(), self.ShowTitle)

        self.btnSelect = wx.Button(panel, label="Select All", pos=(45, 295))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSelectAll, id = self.btnSelect.GetId())

        self.btnUnSelectAll = wx.Button(panel, label="Unselect All*", pos=(173, 295))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnUnSelectAll, id = self.btnUnSelectAll.GetId())

        self.btnApply = wx.Button(panel, label="Apply/Close", pos=(305, 295))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnApply, id = self.btnApply.GetId())

        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "* Note: 'Unselect All' button will not unselect storms that" '\n'
                  "   have already determined", (20, 350))

        self.Show()
        self.Centre()

    def ShowTitle(self, event):
        if self.cb.GetValue():
            self.SetTitle('checkbox.py')
        else: self.SetTitle('')

    def OnSelectAll(self, event):
        self.cb.SetValue(True)

    def OnUnSelectAll(self, event):
        pass

    def OnApply(self, event):
        selection = self.cb.GetValue()


app = wx.App(0)
MyCheckBox(None, -1, 'checkbox.py')
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save checkboxes for later uses. I used `self.cb_list` in the following code.

```
import wx

class MyCheckBox(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Checking Options', size=(470, 400))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.cb_list = []
        for pos in [(120,75), (200,75), (278,75), (356,75), (120,105), (200,105), (278,105), (356,105)]:
            cb = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, '', pos)
            cb.SetValue(False)
            self.cb_list.append(cb)

        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Send output to File", (70, 255))
        self.cb = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, '', (50, 255))
        self.cb.SetValue(True)

        wx.EVT_CHECKBOX(self, self.cb.GetId(), self.ShowTitle)

        self.btnSelect = wx.Button(panel, label="Select All", pos=(45, 295))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSelectAll, id = self.btnSelect.GetId())

        self.btnUnSelectAll = wx.Button(panel, label="Unselect All*", pos=(173, 295))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnUnSelectAll, id = self.btnUnSelectAll.GetId())

        self.btnApply = wx.Button(panel, label="Apply/Close", pos=(305, 295))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnApply, id = self.btnApply.GetId())

        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "* Note: 'Unselect All' button will not unselect storms that" '\n'
                  "   have already determined", (20, 350))

        self.Show()
        self.Centre()

    def ShowTitle(self, event):
        if self.cb.GetValue():
            self.SetTitle('checkbox.py')
        else: self.SetTitle('')

    def OnSelectAll(self, event):
        for cb in self.cb_list:
            cb.SetValue(True)

    def OnUnSelectAll(self, event):
        for cb in self.cb_list:
            cb.SetValue(False)

    def OnApply(self, event):
        selection = self.cb.GetValue()
        for i, cb in enumerate(self.cb_list):
            if cb.GetValue():
                print('{} selected'.format(i))


app = wx.App(0)
MyCheckBox(None, -1, 'checkbox.py')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks. It does the main task of returning checked boxes, select all, and unselect all except unselect all only those which were not selected in the first instance.

Comment: @Ibe, I don't understand what you mean. (I'm not good at English read/write.). Customizing `self.cb_list` will do the task what you want.

Comment: I need to add a dictionary to keep track of which options were checked. This will probably let me unselect only those which were not selected in the first instance.